# Building SQL query with _POST parameters

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to build a dynamic query and am getting an SQL syntax error. The following query statement works correctly when typed out explicitly:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM English WHERE submitdate = '2015-09-30'";
```

However, if I try build the same query with _POST parameters, I get a syntax error, even though the error shows the correct query as above:

```
if ($_POST["lang"] === "de") :
  $query_lang = 'SELECT * FROM German';
elseif ($_POST["lang"] === "en") :
  $query_lang = 'SELECT * FROM English';
else :
  $query_lang = 'SELECT * FROM English, German';
endif;

if ( !empty($_POST["date"]) || $_POST["date"] != "all") :
  $query_date = ' WHERE submitdate = \''. $_POST["date"] . '\'';
else :
  $query_date = '';
endif;

$sql = '"' . $query_lang . $query_date . '"';
```

The error message is

```
Error: "SELECT * FROM English WHERE submitdate = '2015-09-30'"<br>
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'"SELECT * FROM English WHERE submitdate = '2015-09-30'"' at line 1
```

Comment: What is this error you are not telling us about?

Comment: Is it get same pattern '2015-09-30' when you var_dump $_POST["date"]

Comment: The error message is Error: "SELECT * FROM English WHERE submitdate = '2015-09-30'"<br>You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"SELECT * FROM English WHERE submitdate = '2015-09-30'"' at line 1

Comment: Too many quote marks in that string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are writing

```
"SELECT * FROM English WHERE submitdate = '2015-09-30'"
```

Instead of

```
SELECT * FROM English WHERE submitdate = '2015-09-30'
```

Try putting this

```
$sql = $query_lang . $query_date;
```

and see if it works

Comment: Doh! Can't believe I didn't consider that - **facepalm* - thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0):

If `$_POST["lang"]` is not set or different than `'en'` and `'de'`, you end up querying for

```sql
SELECT * FROM English, German WHERE submitdate = '2015-09-30'
```

This will raise an error as `submitdate` is ambiguous between both tables.

EDIT: This is not the answer you're looking for, for now. I leave it here as it will become relevant when you'll have fixed what farugi87 or RiggsFolly suggest.

What you can do in this case is to use `UNION`:

```sql
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT * FROM English 
UNION SELECT * FROM German) t
WHERE submitdate ...
```

This way, you don't have to change anything to the rest of your query, as long as the `English` and `German` tables share the same structure.

If you can, you could also consider merging both tables into one, adding a `lang` column. You could then query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM thisNewTable
WHERE lang = 'en' -- or lang = 'de' or no filter at all in case of 'all'
AND submitdate = ...
```

Comment: Thanks. You are quite right. Why can't both tables be queried for the same date?

Answer (score 0):

You are making your string concatenation more difficult than it needs to be.

Simplify it like this and you will remove the accidental extra quotes around the query.

```
if ( !empty($_POST["date"]) || $_POST["date"] != "all") :
  $query_date = " WHERE submitdate = '{$_POST["date"]}'";
else :
  $query_date = '';
endif;

$sql = $query_lang . $query_date;
```